# What's this part under the ball head called?

Tags: tripod

I recently purchased a dolica tripod. I am looking at the [user manual](http://www.dolica.com/tx570/?rq=manual).
Under the ball-head, there is a ring. I am not sure what to call it. The ring has come off and I am unable to attach the ball head with the ring in place.

The ring is the top most part of the center column on which the ball head sits.

Edit:
Here is the graphic:
[image: Tripod parts]

In this case, this ring has come off and I am unable to screw it back in. I suspect this is a manufacturing fault. This tripod is less than 2 weeks old.

Comment: Maybe if you could add a graphic here with an arrow pointing to the part you are missing and add that graphic to this question, it would be more clear. Also, can you describe the issue you are trying to solve? Are you trying to buy a replacement part? Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a coupler, or a coupler-ring.

It is used to attach the head to the tripod and can take a variety of forms.

Occasionally, the coupler is a "converter" that has a "male" to "male" pins or "female" to "female" thread sockets.

Often, the coupler will also be an "adapter" from 3/8"-16 pitch thread to 1/4"-20.

Threads can be right-hand or left-hand.

To replace it, first try attaching it securely to the tripod and then the head to the coupler.